# Magento 2 - Add programmatically created attribute of custom module to category page after product name

Tags: magento2, frontend

I have created a custom module, which creating a product attribute, now I need to display this attribute on category page,after the product name. How to do this? Thanks everyone!

Comment: what parameter you have passed while creating custom attribute?

Comment: The name of my attribute is: product_vendor

Comment: Have you passed below parameters value true :
`'used_in_product_listing' => true,
  'visible_on_front' => true,`

Comment: just added 'used_in_product_listing' => true, , and 'visible_on_front' is disabled, because It's creating an additional tab in my products pages, and I'm displaying this attribute in frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml in my module